# free tiff viewer for Windows

Tags: gratis, windows-7, image-viewer

I'm looking for free tiff viewer for Windows. I see many of them in Internet, dot sure what to choose. Just very simple to see tiff files. And which doesn't install any additional (ad) software.

Comment: Isn't this already a built-in feature of Windows?

Comment: I can't open these files by Windows Photo Viewer or Paint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to open some TIFF files using standard Windows applications and even IrfanView. But I downloaded [brava! reader](http://www.bravaviewer.com/download-brava-reader) and then I opened these files. I don't know why is this, maybe some specific options for these files.

Answer (score 5):

#### [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/)

- Supports TIFF files among others.
- Free.

I'm curious though what files you have which cannot be viewed by Windows' photo viewer.

Comment: Installed. Get error: Decode error ! Invalid or unsupported TIF file.

Comment: @Alex I guess your file has been corrupted somehow. You could try an [online repair service](https://online.officerecovery.com/de/pixrecovery/) (note: I've never used it and I wouldn't upload confidential data.).

Comment: but I downloaded brava! reader http://www.bravaviewer.com/download-brava-reader and was able to open these files.

Comment: @Alex I'm glad you finally managed to open it. It would be great if you posted an answer yourself, so you can then accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

This one embeds itself into web browsers http://www.alternatiff.com/ -- Being that internet explorer is part of windows, it works there as well. I found it to be very useful for me.

Comment: I don't need TIFF for browser.

Comment: Not a problem. It is just a good program, I hope someone makes use of it.